# WhatsApp web RegExp issue in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

I'm facing RegExp issue with WhatsApp web in Chrome. WhatsApp web is working fine in Firefox but in chrome it gives following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: RegExp.prototype.sticky getter called on non-RegExp object
```

Is there any fix for that? I'm using Chrome `48.0.2560.0 dev-m (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I experienced the same issue and found that it was caused by having the `Enable Experimental Javascript` feature enabled in the `chrome://flags/` experimental features page. Disabling it immediately fixed my problem. Hope this helps!

For those interested, I found the solution [here](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/6102).

Comment: Thanks it helped me too